# Change div background on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the background image of a div region, not the main body on each page load.

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<script>
changeBackground(document.maincontent,imgArray);     
</script> 
</head>
```

Then my function looks like:

```
<script ="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">



function changeBackground(node,images)
      {
        node.style.backgroundImage = "url(\""+images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)]+"\")"; 
      }

var imgArray = new Array();
      imgArray[0] = "img/bg1.jpg";
      imgArray[1] = "img/bg2.jpg";
      imgArray[2] = "img/bg3.jpg";
      imgArray[3] = "img/bg4.jpg";    
      imgArray[4] = "img/bg5.jpg";

</script>
```

I found this on a tutorial, it worked for the body but for reasons unknown doesn't work with the div region?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
changeBackground(document.getElementById("maincontent"),imgArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Insteaf of using:

```
document.maincontent
```

use:

```
document.getElementById('IdOfDivHere')
```

This is the most standard way of obtaining elements on the page. In your `changeBackground` method you may also want to check for the existence of the element before operating on it:

```
if(node)
{
  /* Do the work */
}
```